# Is there a term for controllers with the game built in?

Tags: controllers, terminology, hardware

There exist games which don’t play on a console, and don’t have their own display — rather, the controller has a video out cord which you can plug into your TV.

Is there a term for this type of game/controller hybrid device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are most commonly known as "Plug & Play games", but can also be called "TV games" or "handheld TV games" by some retailers. They are a type of [dedicated console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedicated_console#Handheld_TV_games).

[[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handheld_TV_game)]